# AutoHotKey not detecting the right key

Tags: scripting, autohotkey, hotkeys

So I've made a script to snipe rare cars from Auction House in FH5. Simple script, which should work like I've written it.

Thats my script at the point, it's not doing what it should

```
 Send {Enter}
    Sleep, 500
    Send {Enter}

    PixelGetColor, PixelCol0, 730, 270
    if (PixelCol0 = "0xF7F7F7") ;car found
    {
        Loop
        {   
            PixelGetColor, PixelCol1, 900, 240
            if (PixelCol1 != "0xF7F7F7") ;site has loaded/able to press Y
            {
                Sleep, 500
                Send {Y}
            }

            PixelGetColor, PixelCol2, 671, 444
            if (PixelCol2 = "0x351734") ;Check if Y was pressed "correctly"
            {
                Sleep, 500
                FOUNDCAR = 1
                break
            }
        }
```

regarding the X and Y points of the pixels and the colors, it should work. I have another script to get mouse position and pixel color, so it's 100% correct.

My problem now is, it presses ENTER for 2 times, which works but when it has to press Y to open Auctiondetails, it's not opening the Auctiondetails but the Auction itselfs, like you press Enter again. If you're into FH5, you know what I mean!!!

Would be great if someone knows how to fix that, I'm trying to fix that BS since 2 days now and I'm so close to rage!!!!

Thank you!

Comment: Try replacing **Send {Y}** by **`Send y`**

Comment: @user3419297 Already tried. But same result, it always sends an ENTER instead of Y

Answer (score 0):

I would start with making sure that PixelGetColor works correctly. Without any CoordMode settings the coordinates are relative to the window, and it might be that your mousecoordinates were relative to the screen, thus looking at the wrong pixel. I would replace the code with simple messages that show you the outcome of the PixelGetColor. Use two FH5 windows, one with the right colors and one without, just to check the PixelGetColor behaviour first.